# C: Convert special ASCII characters ÄÖÜ

Tags: c, ascii, character, diacritics

I'm reading out text from a website with Curl. All the rawdata is being returned character by character with

```
return memEof(mp) ? EOF : (int)(*(unsigned char *)(mp->readptr++));
```

My problem is, that all the special characters such as ÄÖÜäöüß etc are all wrong and look very cryptic. I'm currently correcting them manually by adjusting their values using this table:

http://www.barcoderesource.com/barcodeasciicharacters.shtml

I was wondering now, if there is a more elegant way to do this and how others approach these kinds of issues.

Comment: This is a character encoding issue. What encoding is the website in and what encoding are you using internally? (UTF-8? ISO 8559-1 / Latin-1? Windows 1252?)

Comment: The table you are using is wrong. It's titled “ASCII” but it's not: ASCII only goes up to 127. Looks more like Windows-1252, a superset of ASCII.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an encoding issue. If you read data byte by byte, you can handle correctly and easily just single byte encodings (like ISO-8859 "family" and many more), provided you have a way to convert them correctly in a target encoding, if you need. But with encodings like UTF-8 you are less lucky, since to get the right code you need to read 1 byte, or maybe 2, or maybe three... If you stream them into a string, and print the string altogether, and the output device intended encoding is the same of the input encoding, you get the right char shown anyway.

If it does not happen, and you are not printing each byte as if it were a symbol for sure, then the output device intended encoding does not match the one the string is written with.

If the output, once you print the string "altogether" looks ok, then the problem is that you are interpreting each byte as a single character, while it is not (you have a multibyte encoding for char like the special one you mentioned; likely it is UTF-8 but it could be not too).

If you get equal results in both cases (when you print each byte one by one and when you output a string that keeps the whole byte sequence), then the output device intended encoding is a single byte encoding like the input encoding, but they do not match.

Further details would need to know how you collect the bytes you read in order to print them and say that they looks cryptic.

An example.

```
const char *string = "\xc3\xa8\xc3\xb2\xc3\xa0";
int i;
for(i = 0; string[i] != 0; i++)
{
   printf("%c\n", string[i]);
   // using \n is important; if you "sequence" the chars and the output enc is
   // utf-8, you obtain the right output
}
printf("%s", string);
```

You obtain different results if the output device encoding is UTF-8; if it is a single byte encoding, you obtain the same output (newlines apart), but it is "wrong" with respect to what I've written, i.e. èòà.

The "same" text is, in Latin1, "\xe8\xf2\xe0". Latin1 is a single byte encoding, so the above speech applies. If printed on a terminal understanding utf-8, you can obtain something like �� ...

So, encodings matter, device/format output encoding matters too, and you must be aware of both in order to handle and show properly the text. (About format, an example could be html, where you can specify the encoding of the content... you must be coherent, and you'll see everything fine)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have to use an external library like [iconv](http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/) to create a `wchar_t` string which contains the data. This depends on the used character encoding.